# How to dismiss alert or progress dialog in tabs and prevent accessing tabs beginning?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have a tabbed activity which has 3 tabs. Here its main acticity:

```
public class TabbedActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed2);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setTitle("Vocabulary Paractices");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tabbed_activity2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1)
            {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level1fragment, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
            else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==2)
            {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level2fragment, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
            else
            {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level3fragment, container, false);
                return rootView;
            } 
        }
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {    
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    level1fragment tab1= new level1fragment();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    level2fragment tab2= new level2fragment();
                    return tab2;
                case 2:
                    level3fragment tab3= new level3fragment();
                    return tab3;
                default:
                    return null;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Level 1";
                case 1:
                    return "Level 2";
                case 2:
                    return "Level 3";
                default:
                    return null;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

One of the fragment:

```
    public class level1fragment extends Fragment {
    private Random randomGenerator;
    private TextView translation;
    private TextView idofcaps;
    private EditText useranswer;
    private CheckBox checkbox;
    private ImageView caps,nocheckbox;
    private Button controlanswer;
    private DatabaseReference myDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAut;

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public level1fragment() {
    }

    public static level1fragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        level1fragment fragment = new level1fragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level1fragment, container, false);
        mAut= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        caps=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.capslevel1);
        translation=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.translationlevel1);
        idofcaps=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.idofcapslevel1);
        useranswer=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.useranswerlevel1);
        controlanswer=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.controlbuttonlevel1);
        nocheckbox=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.nocheckboxlevel1);

        String user_id = mAut.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        myDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference current_user_db = myDatabase.child("Users").child(user_id);
        final DatabaseReference myDataSelect = myDatabase.child("Caps").child("Level 1").child("Questions");
        final ProgressDialog myProgress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"Wait","Test is preparing",true);
        myDataSelect.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final List<String> lstd = new ArrayList<String>(); // Result will be holded Here

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    lstd.add(String.valueOf(ds.getKey()));
                    DatabaseReference solved= current_user_db.child("Caps").child("Level 1").child("Solved");

                    solved.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            final List<String> solved = new ArrayList<String>(); 
                            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                solved.add(String.valueOf(ds.getValue()));

                                lstd.removeAll(solved);
                                if (lstd.isEmpty()) {
                                    ViewPager contain= (ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.container);
                                    contain.setCurrentItem(1);
                                }

        else {
      randomGenerator = new Random();
      int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(lstd.size());
      String item = lstd.get(index);
      idofcaps.setText(item);
     final DatabaseReference capsSelect = myDataSelect.child(item);
       capsSelect.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dss) {
String post_Image = (String) dss.child("Image").getValue();                                  Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(post_Image).into(caps);
String translation_caps = (String) dss.child("Translation").getValue();
translation.setText(translation_caps);
}
       @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
       @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });
                    myProgress.dismiss();

                }}
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });

        controlanswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String ua= useranswer.getText().toString().trim();
                String aa= translation.getText().toString();

                if (ua.equalsIgnoreCase(aa)) {

                    useranswer.setText("");
                    String b=idofcaps.getText().toString();
                    final DatabaseReference solved = current_user_db.child("Caps").child("Level 1").child("Solved").push();
                    solved.setValue(b);

                    myDataSelect.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            final List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(); 
                            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                lst.add(String.valueOf(ds.getKey()));
                                solved.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        final List<String> solved = new ArrayList<String>(); 
                                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                            solved.add(String.valueOf(ds.getValue()));
                                            lst.removeAll(solved);
                                            if(lst.isEmpty())
                                            {

                                            }

 else {
      randomGenerator = new Random();
      int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(lst.size());
      String item = lst.get(index);
      idofcaps.setText(item);

  final DatabaseReference capsSelect = myDataSelect.child(item);
                                               capsSelect.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dss) {

                                                        String post_Image = (String) dss.child("Image").getValue();
                                                        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(post_Image).into(caps);
                                                        String post_name = (String) dss.child("Translation").getValue();
                                                        translation.setText(post_name);
                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                                    }
                                                });

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                    nocheckbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
                else
                {
                    nocheckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

I know it is too much. I have lots of questions this is why I add a lof them. I'm new at Android. In this part, I'm trying to do a kind of test/quiz app. I will have 3 levels at the beginning. I want to show them in a tab but I don't want to access all tabs at the beginning. I want to make if the questions in the tab1 solved correctly, tab2 opens. I'm retrieving questions from firebase and store them in a list. I tried the put Alert Dialog in if lst.isEmpty() part like:

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                         builder.setTitle("Congratulations!");
                         builder.setMessage("You finished Level 1. Do you want to start Level 2?");
           builder.setNegativeButton("Not now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        }
                                    });

           builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                    {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                                        {
ViewPager contain= (ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.container);
                                    contain.setCurrentItem(1);
dialog.dissmiss();
                                        }

                                    });
```

However Alert Dialog doesn't dissapper. Passing the tab2 is okey but on the screen dialog never closes. I tried Toast Message. It has the same problem. Around ten times message shows then dissappear. Even I close the app on my phone screen message doesn't close. Where am I wrong? Besides this, even tab1 and tab2 questions are finished this toast message or alert dialog start from the tab1 after that shows in the tab2. How I can make them only one time appear? I mean when user click one of the buttons it never shows up again. Also, progress dialog never dismiss, too. Besides these, after some swiping toolbar is dissapering. And didn't understand why and how to prevent it.

Comment: Ask the firebase question in a separate question.

Comment: Okey. I edited.

Comment: Where in your code are you using the `AlertBuilder`?  I don't see it in your activity or in the fragment.

Comment: if(lst.isEmpty()) { in here }. I write it empty because I tried toast message at the same place. I mention it in the text.